# Yii2 activerecord select custom attributes from related table

Tags: php, select, activerecord, yii2

When I'm trying to select custom attributes from record

```
 $data = Emotion::find()
        ->select('em_id, em_name, tbl_post.post_id, tbl_post.post_header')
        ->where(['em_id' => $id])
        ->joinWith('posts')
        ->one();
```

I've got an answer model, where related field have full set of table fields.
Trace message looks like this:

```
 app\models\Emotion#1
 ( [yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:_attributes] => 
[ 'em_id' => 4
'em_name' => 'test_em']
[yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:_related] => 
[ 'posts' => 
[ 0 => app\models\Post#2 ( [yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:_attributes] => 
[ 'post_id' => 10
'post_header' => 'some header' 
'post_date' => '2015-06-24 13:40:25', 
'post_descr' => 'Rocco, continue the joke'
'post_content' => 'test content'...
```

So, maybe i did something wrong or this is a framework issue.

Found a workaround here: [Yii2 GitHub issue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/9495)

Which for my case looks like this:

```
$data = Emotion::find()
        ->select('em_id, em_name, tbl_post.post_id, tbl_post.post_header')
        ->where(['em_id' => $id])
        ->joinWith('posts')
        ->createCommand()
        ->queryAll();
```

And the output of this request will be an raw array.
Is there an another way to have an ActiveRecord object in a response data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply modify the relation query, e.g. :

```
$data = Emotion::find()
    ->select('em_id, em_name')
    ->where(['em_id' => $id])
    ->with([
        'posts' => function($query) {
            $query->select('post_id, post_header');
        }
    ])->one();
```

And you don't need [`joinWith`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#joinWith()-detail) since you don't use posts in the main query.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's really helpful.